# Multiple imputation and inverse probability weighting for multiple treatment?

Tags: propensity-scores, multiple-imputation, multinomial-logit

I am analyzing observational study data. My predictor variable is `tg4` with 4 categories (0,1,2,3) and my response variable is `dm` (0,1).
my analysis step as follow:

1. I use mice package to impute missing data as follow
   `chi<-chi %>% mice(seed = 123, print = FALSE, m=5)`
2. Covariate balance assessment using standardized mean differences (SMD) (I tried to use `tableone` package) but it does not work because I have 5 imputed datasets.
3. calculating propensity score using multinomial logistic regression.
4. calculating weight
5. calculating pooled hazard ratio for all dataset

```r
suvtime<-Surv(time=chi$time,event = chi$dm)
fit<- coxph(suvtime~tg4,data=chi, weights =weights)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of packages you can use for this. The `MatchThem` package performs matching and IPW in multiply imputed datasets; you can supply it with a `mids` objects from `mice` and it will perform the weighting in all of the imputed datasets. It calls the `weightit()` function from the `WeightIt` package to do the weighting. You can then use the `bal.tab()` function in `cobalt` to assess balance on the imputed datasets. Once you have achieved balance, you can fit your outcome model using the `with()` function in `MatchThem`.

I recommend you 1) look at the `WeightIt` package and see its capabilities for multi-category treatments (there are many options beyond multinomial logistic regression); 2) look at the `MatchThem` package for applying `WeightIt` functionality to multiply imputed datasets and estimating treatment effects pooling across the datasets; and 3) look at the `cobalt` package for assessing balance generally and specifically with multiply imputed data and multi-category treatments. I am the author of all three of these packages, and they are designed to work seamlessly together specifically for this type of analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I have a question for the output of assessing balance generally.  When I use cobalt package for assessing balance bal.tab ().I got pairwise comparison instead of comparing all categories at ones(i.e I would like to get mean and SMD as one summary table)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You can request means using `disp.means = TRUE`. Read the `cobalt` vignettes carefully; your question is likely answered in it.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.